# Complete the task in a given amount of time

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, time

I would like to add a feature to my web application to do some work when specific amount of time will pass. I want to know how long will it last to the end and perform some task when the time is over.
Its will be .net core 2.0 web app.

I would like it to be possible to give more such events to be carried out e.g. 1000 task in some period of time. It can be seconds, minutes, days.

I don't know what tool can I use to handle this problem. What tool is the best to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn't even contain any question. I'm really confused what you're asking for. What's the problem? What's not working? Please read the help articles on asking questions and fix your question so we're able to help you.

Comment: Ummm... Task Scheduler? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page

Comment: in web application?

Comment: just store the schedules somewhere  , and use a [Background Service ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to do that . Update the record when some task done .